# How to create symbolic links in the output .tar.gz file?

Tags: ant, tar, symlink

We are using Windows as a development system and Ant to create the platform-specific bundles. For the macOS specific bundle (`.tar.gz` file) we are using the tar task. I want to create a symbolic link in the output .tar.gz file which points to another file in the same `.tar.gz` file. Can this be done using Ant?

Comment: Related: [Straightforward, easy way to create symbolic links on Windows?](https://superuser.com/q/197273/87805)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge stock Ant can't do this.

Answer (score 1):

Bit late, but suggestion: you can create tar archives containing symlinks from windows command line using cygwin.

```
$ ln -s abc def
$ tar cf test.tar abc def
$ tar tvf test.tar
-rw-r--r-- shegny/Domain Users 0 2013-04-26 10:25 abc
lrwxrwxrwx shegny/Domain Users 0 2013-04-26 10:25 def -> abc
```

Answer (score -2):

You cannot create a symbolic link on Windows.  Therefore, the Symlink Ant task would not work properly.  One option would be to run a continuous build server on a Mac machine.  Then, you could run that task at regular intervals and the Symlink Ant task would work.

Comment: Maybe there is a misunderstanding: I don't want to create a symlink in the operating system's file system, but only in the .tar.gz file which is created by ANT's tar task.

Comment: It's not true that you cannot create a symbolic link in Windows.  mklink is the command line tool; CreateSymbolicLink is the Win32 function. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363866(VS.85).aspx